# Intelligent copy/paste (Auto Fill Form) with Tampermonkey

Tags: tampermonkey, autofill

I have seen an automatic form filling system using with tampermonkey before.

The system worked like this;

1- There would be a site where the form had to be filled,https://prnt.sc/IITZQhg9i5AH
2- And regardless of the site, a box would pop up there. If the information requested in the form was copied/pasted in this part in a mixed way, the form would be filled automatically.

How can I do this with tampermonkey? More precisely, is this system still possible? Or is there a different system that works like this?

Making a so-called "smart copy/paste" system with an external website tampermonkey or an x application

Comment: Yes, it is possible to complete online forms with TM. However, your question is not clear - please explain the part re a box popping-up with mixed data? No idea what you mean by that. Also, what is your knowledge-level re javascript and css selectors? If excellent, this is not a difficult task. If not so good, we can help - but you must start first and paste-in what you have so far... Most likely, we will need to see the site (or at the very least, screenshots of the HTML from DevTools) and examples of what a populated pop-up box would look like. Best wishes with this project.